# Suppressing Dialog on Printing PDF in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open up and print a number of PDF files in Excel. For various reasons, I need to open the file and use the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer so that I can do some manipulation later. My idea was to use a shell command to invoke Adobe Acrobat and open the file, print the file to a new .pdf, and then close the file. The problem is that I can't figure out how to rename my file.

So far, I'm using this code:

```
Dim command As String
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 7
    
'Grabbed Application.ActivePrinter earlier and used this below
command = "acrobat /t " & tempName "Microsoft Print to PDF on NE03:" "Microsoft Print to PDF on NE03:"

wsh.Run command, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

The file opens and closes as expected in Adobe, but it doesn't seem to print anything (and I can't figure out a way to give it a name). Is there a way to feed it a new file name? Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: if you have acrobat pro or standard you can use the built-in libraries via vba to manipulate the PDFs.

Comment: Hi Scott, I've tried using Acrobat.AcroApp to do something like .PrintPages(1, pageCount, 2, True, True), but hadn't had luck there either.